# How to publish free unity game to Google Play?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play, publishing

I have several questions:

1. Unity gives a default company and youtube tutorials shows the guys always enter a company name. Must I do the same although Im a solo developer? do I enter a random name?
2. One tutorial shows that there is no need to change the api level (the default is the highest installed) where as another tutorial shows that you must change the api level to Google Plays (current level 31)
3. In the Google Console there is a privacy policy url, what is that and must I provide one?
4. There is an option to tick whether your game have ads, does it mean that other can insert ads into the game or something I provide?, also is it recommended although my game is pretty simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the answers to your questions:

1. Yes, you can randomly put any company name you want to, but keep in mind that when you publish a game again, it would be better if it's under the same company name; that'll help you grow better. If you're still interested in more about privacy and company laws, [here's the detailed video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8eAW-7Js7NA) that I would suggest.
2. Here are the [Google Play's API level requirement](https://developer.android.com/google/play/requirements/target-sdk.):

   > When you upload an APK, it must meet Google Play's target API level
   > requirements. New apps must target Android 12 (API level 31) or
   > higher; except for Wear OS apps, which must target Android 11 (API
   > level 30) or higher.
3. There is no specific standard for a privacy policy. Looking at some favourite apps' approaches will help you know how to write a privacy policy. Here's an example: [PRIVACY_POLICY.md](https://github.com/WrichikBasu/ShakeAlarmClock/blob/master/PRIVACY_POLICY.md).

   Google Play's support page now mentions that:

   > All developers that have an app published on Google Play must complete
   > the Data safety form, including apps on internal, closed, open, or
   > production testing tracks.
   >
   > Even developers with apps that do not collect any user data are
   > required to complete this form and provide a link to their privacy
   > policy. In this case, the completed form and privacy policy can
   > indicate that no user data is collected or shared.
4. For ads, you must enable ads through code too. Here's a simple example of [UnityAds](https://docs.unity3d.com/540/Documentation/Manual/UnityAdsHowTo.html). There are three types of ads in an app generally:

   - [Interstitial Ads](https://docs.unity.com/ads/ImplementingBasicAdsUnity.html): These ads are shown somewhere, like when you have switched scenes, clicked on something special etc.
   - [Rewarded Ads](https://docs.unity.com/ads/ImplementingRewardedAdsUnity.html): These ads are shown when the user gets in-game rewards like a powerup or get some coins by watching the ads.
   - [Banner Ads](https://docs.unity.com/ads/ImplementingBannerAdsUnity.html): These ads in your app; whenever someone opens your app, they'll be shown an ad at the bottom of your screen.

   You can add any of these ads in your application, and google accordingly will show ads in your app of some other apps/games.

   If you wish to show your ads in your own app, you have to enable [cross promo ads](https://docs.unity.com/ads/ImplementingCrossPromoAds.html) for that, and implement them accordingly in your app. And if you want to show your app ads to some other apps then you need to give ads to [Google Ads](https://ads.google.com/) and set your budget accordingly

   And for its last part, No, it isn't necessary to show ads in your game if you. Ads are only necessary if you wish to earn some bucks from it. So I would recommend you make your app worth people's use. Then if it's showing a good response, you can enable your ads after that; otherwise, there's no need to have a headache adding ads in your app.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, that's your pick.
2. Now it requires at least 30.
3. Yes, it's a must.
4. If you want to monetize your game, you have to implement ads in the game.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I dont understand number 3, how do I make one of those?

Comment: Get any major account's privacy policy and place it anywhere. It could be a blog or a website.

Comment: Could I have an example? Also is privacy policy generator also viable?